# merging two dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I have two dictionary as follows

```
{'abc':1,'xyz':8,'pqr':9,'ddd': 22}
{0:'pqr',1:'xyz',2:'abc',3:'ddd'}
```

My objective is to get a new dictionary in the following format

```
{2:1 1:8 0:9 3:22}
```

I am combing the value of first dictionary as value of the new dictionary and the key of dictionary 2 whose value matches with the key of the dictionary 1 as key of the the new dictionary.

I have written some code as follows:

```
for list1elem in listofemail[1:]:
    print(list1elem)
    for the_key, the_value in list1elem.items():
        the_key = [k for k, v in vocab_dic.items() if v == the_key]
```

But my code is not replacing the old key with the new one.  Both of my dictionaries are large, containing 25000 key/value pair. So it is taking a lot of time.  What would be the fastest way to do this?

Comment: there is a syntax error in the second dictionary. Remove the extra comma

Comment: What do you mean by "combing" here?

Answer (score 6):

this

```
d1 = {'abc':1, 'xyz':8, 'pqr':9, 'ddd':22}
d2 = {0:'pqr', 1:'xyz', 2:'abc', 3:'ddd'}

d = {k:d1[v] for k,v in d2.items()}
```

produces

```
{0: 9, 1: 8, 2: 1, 3: 22}
```

Basically, it goes through every item (key and value) in `d2` and it uses the value `v` as the key into `d1` to get its corresponding value. It then combines the latter with the original key `k` to create the item that goes into the resulting dictionary.

Side note: there is no error checking. It assumes the values in `d2` are present in `d1` as keys.

In case you wanted a specific value if the key is missing (e.g. -1), you can do

```
d = {k:d1.get(v, -1) for k,v in d2.items()}
```

Otherwise, in case you wanted to omit inserting the item altogether, use

```
d = {k:d1[v] for k,v in d2.items() if v in d1}
```

Comment: @zstewart yes, you beat me to it, I am adding the options. BTW your code is flawed: it's `v` that must be in `d1` and dictionaries give back keys only as an iterable (use `.items` instead)

Comment: what should I do if my dictionary two has some more value which dictionary want doesn't have.

Comment: Well, that is up to you to decide. At the bottom of the answer, I give you two options: you can either insert a fixed value with the missing key or otherwise avoid inserting such key altogether (i.e. skip it)

Comment: its woking fine now.The only problem I am having now is actually I have a list of dictionary as follows

Comment: @akira, Please accept sufficient answers with the checkmark button.  It's worth +2 rep to you.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following:

```
In [1]: a1 = {'abc':1,'xyz':8,'pqr':9,'ddd': 22} 

In [2]: a2 = {0:'pqr', 1:'xyz',2:'abc',3:'ddd'}

In [3]: a3 = {}

In [4]: for key, value in a2.items():
            # extra checking if the value of 2nd dictionary is a key in 1st dictionary
            if value in a1: 
                a3[key] = a1[value]    

In [5]: a3 
Out[5]: {0: 9, 1: 8, 2: 1, 3: 22} # desired result
```

Here we iterate over the 2nd dictionary and check if values of 2nd dictionary are present as keys in the 1st dictionary using the `in` operator. If they are present, then we assign the key of the 2nd dictionary as the key of `a3` and value as the value obtained on performing lookup in the 1st dictionary with the `value` of 2nd dictionary.